# Assign onclick event inside loop

Tags: javascript

Working with onclick event assigned inside the loop , but problem has occured

```
matej.prototype.animacia = function () {
 var tab = document.getElementById("table");
 var x = tab.querySelectorAll(".lol td");
var kontrola=true;
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].onclick = function (e) {
         e = e ? e : window.event;
         var decko = e.target.querySelector(".bodky");
         var bastard = e.target.querySelector(".hidden");
         var hore = 0;

             kontrola=false;
         var id = function () {

             decko.style.opacity = 1 - hore;
             hore += 0.05;
             if (hore < 1) {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     id();
                 }, 10);
             } else {
                 decko.style.display = "none";
                 decko.style.opacity = 0;
                 (function (e) {
                     e = e ? e : window.event;
                     var dole = 0;
                     var di = function () {
                         bastard.style.display = "inline";
                         bastard.style.opacity = 0 + dole;
                         dole += 0.05;
                         if (dole < 1) {
                             setTimeout(function () {
                                 di();
                             }, 100);
                         } else {
                             bastard.style.opacity = 1;
                         }

                     };
                     di();
                 })();
             }

         };
         id();

     }
        };}
```

It "works" as expected but i have to click on the "TD" elements in order(from the last one to the first) otherwise it will throw an error . Why does it happen ?
working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/qxd32hkk/5/

Comment: Are the variable names really describing the content?

Comment: When I try your fiddle example in FF/Windows 7 I don't need to click on the elements in order.  I clicked randomly, and some worked and others didn't.  Eve, then 94 worked.  Jackson gave an error, then Jill worked.  Jackson started working after Jill.  The pattern isn't consistent on multiple tries.  I can't be sure about this, but I think the recursive calls may be taxing the browser such that running one onClick() prevents others from working.

Comment: As you haven't provided the full code.From assumption i think you are facing a closure related problem.Add a wrapping immediately invoked function right after your for loop might solve your problem

Comment: yes variable are describing the content :) // tried wrapping in immadiately invoking function but didnt work

Comment: You'd do well to simplify this. Take advantage of the fact that events bubble up and set your event handler once on your table, and use the event properties to determine which cell was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive calls to `setTimeout` to handle the transitions, along with the event handlers added to every `<td>` probably give some issue with scope, and a variable somewhere is likely being overwritten when it shouldn't be.

I've simplified the `animacia()` function to add one event handler to the table and use `event.target` to identify the element that's been clicked.

Further, I've added a CSS transition to the style sheet so that the browser controls the fadeOut and fadeIn animations instead of using JavaScript to do it. The fade out-fadein sequence is controlled by an event handler.

The new CSS:

```
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display:none;
            opacity:0;
            transition:opacity 2s;
        }
        .bodky {
            opacity:1;
            display:inline;
            transition:opacity 200ms;
        }
        td{
            cursor:pointer;
            width:200px;
        }
    </style>
```

The new `animacia()` function:

```
   matej.prototype.animacia = function () {

        // Add an event listener to the table so that only one is required.
        // Use event.target to get the element that was clicked
        table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            // Get the elements we're going to fade
            let decko = e.target.closest('td').querySelector(".bodky");
            let bastard = e.target.closest('td').querySelector(".hidden");

            // Set up a fadeOutFadeIn function so that it's easy to identify later
            // This will be called by the transitionend event on our fadeOut element
            // It removes the faded element from display, add the new element and starts the fade In
            let fadeOutFadeIn = function(){
                decko.offsetHeight;  // This forces a reflow to ensure that the transition is displayed.
                decko.style.display = 'none';
                bastard.style.display='inline';
                decko.offsetHeight;
                bastard.style.opacity = 1;
                decko.removeEventListener('transitionend', fadeOutFadeIn);
            };

            // Add the transtionend handler to the element that will be faded out
            decko.addEventListener('transitionend', fadeOutFadeIn);
            // Set the new opacity for the fadeOut element. CSS controls the duration
            decko.style.opacity = 0;
        });
        }
```

Here's the complete code as a working snippet.

```js
window.onerror = function (m, u, l) {
        alert('Javascript Error: ' + m + '\nURL: ' + u + '\nLine Number: ' + l);
        return true;
    }
    var lol = document.getElementsByClassName("lol");
    var kek = [];

    function matej() {
        var self = this;

        self.children = lol;
        self.before = [];
        self.after = [];




        self.shortIt();

        self.nahrada();
        self.animacia();

    }

    matej.prototype.shortIt = function () {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.children, function (element) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.children, function (td) {
                var range = document.createRange();
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
                range.setStart(td.childNodes[0], 1);
                range.setEnd(td.childNodes[0], td.childNodes[0].length);
                range.surroundContents(span);

            });
        });
    };


    matej.prototype.nahrada = function () {
        var skryty = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(skryty, function (element) {
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            var y = document.createTextNode("...");
            span.appendChild(y);
            span.setAttribute("class", "bodky");
            var tato = element.parentNode;
            tato.insertBefore(span, element);

        });
    };


    matej.prototype.animacia = function () {

        // Add an event listener to the table so that only one is required.
        // Use event.target to get the element that was clicked
        table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            // Get the elements we're going to fade
            let decko = e.target.closest('td').querySelector(".bodky");
            let bastard = e.target.closest('td').querySelector(".hidden");

            // Set up a fadeOutFadeIn function so that it's easy to identify later
            // This will be called by the transitionend event on our fadeOut element
            // It removes the faded element from display, add the new element and starts the fade In
            let fadeOutFadeIn = function(){
                decko.offsetHeight;  // This forces a reflow to ensure that the transition is displayed.
                decko.style.display = 'none';
                bastard.style.display='inline';
                decko.offsetHeight;
                bastard.style.opacity = 1;
                decko.removeEventListener('transitionend', fadeOutFadeIn);
            };

            // Add the transtionend handler to the element that will be faded out
            decko.addEventListener('transitionend', fadeOutFadeIn);
            // Set the new opacity for the fadeOut element. CSS controls the duration
            decko.style.opacity = 0;
        });
        }


    var sprav = new matej();
```

```css
.hidden {
            display:none;
            opacity:0;
            transition:opacity 2s;
        }
        .bodky {
            opacity:1;
            display:inline;
            transition:opacity 200ms;
        }
        td{
            cursor:pointer;
            width:100px;
        }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="table">
<tr class="lol">
    <td data-fact="true">Jill</td>
    <td data-fact="true">Jilla</td>
    <td data-fact="true">50</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lol">
    <td data-fact="true">Eve</td>
    <td data-fact="true">Jackson</td>
    <td data-fact="true">94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```